# is karate support <= operator matching

Tags: api, karate

i want to check length of particular array using <= operator

- match bicCameraResponse.items.length <= 15
  but it is not working getting error "syntax error, expected '==' for match"

is there any other way to check this?

Answer (score 1):

Sample code:

```
Feature: Array Length

Scenario: Check array length
        * def a = [1,2,3]
        * match a == '#[_ <= 3]'
```